# How to get login form CSRF protection working in Symfony 2.1?

Tags: symfony, csrf, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I can't seem to get login form CSRF protection working happily using Symfony 2.1.

In config.yml, csrf_protection is set to true. The login form is rendering a hidden input named 'form[_token]']. In security.yml:

```
csrf_parameter: form[_token]
intention: authenticate
```

With this configuration, I can login without issue. But the CSRF token is not being checked. I confirmed this by removing the hidden input field before submitting the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="9b2f5d5efabb938ff8d83c2c8318db1377a3ef16">
```

If I add a csrf_provider configuration setting to security.yml, I can no longer login, getting the error "Invalid CSRF token"

```
csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

I've read whatever I could find on the topic and nothing seems to work correctly - except for what I read in this article: http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-cross-site-request-forgery/. That stuff seems to have been pulled into Friends of Symfony: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/469, which I am not using.

The post instructs you to:

- generate a token manually in the loginAction:

  $csrfToken = $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authentication');
- send it to the view
- and render it manually in the form

which is annoying.

The question basically comes down to - should CSRF protection work in Symfony 2.1 for login forms using only configuration settings, or will I need to modify my loginAction and template to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You pass wrong parameter to generateCsrfToken() method. It should be 'authenticate', not 'authentication' - this is why you get invalid token. Do the following to make it work:

```
secured_area:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
```

then add the following value to the response of your login controller:

```
'csrf_token' => $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
```

and finally in your template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
```

Tested with Symfony 2.3.1

Comment: this works on 2.5 without adding anything to login controller (only first and last step).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - when I posted a form I got "invalid csrf token" error.

I found out that the PHPSESSID is different on every request. This caused the problem, because csrf token is generated by using that cookie content.

The sollution: set
  cookie_secure:     false

in your config.yml or just remove the line from the config (this can be found under framework -> session)

The default (true) setting didn't cause any problem in google chrome, but mozzila and other browsers raised this error.